# D3 Hierarchical Edge Bundling - initial link colors

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, colors, bundle-layout

I use [hierarchical edge bundling](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7607999).

[image]

It works fine. But I want to specify colors of links from json source. How can I do it? In documentation links are just strings, I cann't provide any additional properties.